# Error: cannot find World!.map: No such file or directory. Using Atmel studio 6 and CEENBot API

Tags: c++, c, atmel

So I am making my Hello world program, and it is like this:

```
#include "lib-includes/capi324v221.h" 

void CBOT_main(void)
{   
    LCD_open();

    if (!LCD_OPEN) {

        while (true); // loop forever   
    }

    else {
        LCD_printf("Hello, World!");
        while(true); // loop forever
    }   
}
```

Can anyone help with this? I am sorry if it is a little vague; it is all the info I know for the most part.

Comment: Just to clear up, I am programming CEENBots, which use Atmel-based processors.

Comment: Maybe you could say what the problem is? Doesn't it print on the display? Doesn't compile (in which case you should provide the errors)? Something else completely? It's kind of hard to help you when you don't say what is wrong.

Comment: @scrat101: did my answer below solve your problem? If so could you accept it as an answer?

Comment: It's a good answer. My project name was Hello, World!. I can see the space and exclamation marks being the issue. Besides, my techie friend of mine said the same thing when I asked him if what you said was true. Time to fire up my laptop and fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all what are those `while` loops doing there? My first reaction is to get rid of those.

I have no personal experience with programming CEENBots\your IDE, but based on the error description in the question title I suspect your source file has a `!` in it which messes up the build process (it complains about a `World!.map` file, best to keep special characters out of filenames).

edit:
To extend upon what Öö Tiib states below, get rid of the space and comma too :)

Comment: +1 More likely the problem is because of a space in file name like "Hello World!.cpp", but your answer seems to be useful anyway.  ;)